# Why is Python not catching this exception?

Tags: python, ansys

I have the following code:

```
# coding=utf-8

import os
import csv

os.chdir("K:\dozr\CHW2204\PS\FEA_Ansys\Suction_Bucket_Skirt\Working_Area\Python")

part_name = []
thickness = []
with open('names.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    csvfile.readline() # throw away header
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        part_name.append(row[0])
        thickness.append(row[1])


# Assign thickness to PartName
A = ExtAPI.DataModel.Project.Model.Geometry.Children[0]
n = A.Children.Count

i=0
for B in A.Children:
    try:
        indx = part_name.index(B.Name)
        B.Thickness = Quantity(thickness[indx])
    except:
        pass
        i=i+1

print("Parts not detected in list")
print(i)
```

But the code gives this error:
[image]

The code is not written by me but has worked in the past, although I could have made a mistake copying it. I am pretty sure this is exactly the error that the "try" block is intended to catch. Any idea why it is not working?

EDIT:
It shows the line here:
[image]
I'll see if I can get the traceback log too. I am new with scripting in Ansys.

EDIT_2:
The pop-up is not just for information. The code stops, the final pop-up that would list missing parts does not come. Pressing play again won't continue the execution.

The weirdest thing is that it runs fine from the immediate window. I think KEN Y-N has a very good point that it is an IDE issue, and not a Python issue.

Comment: The code says "list.index(item)" nowhere. I think the exception comes from somewhere not shown here. It would be really helpful to see a stack trace.

Comment: How can you be sure that this error occurs on the line you have indicated?

Comment: Or use a debugger to find out where the exception comes from. From the screenshot we can see that you should be able to use a debugger easily by using the green "play" button.

Comment: broad except: is typically not encouarged, but regardless, it should catch every exceptions (it even catches keyboardinterruption), so it's very likely that it's not from that line.

Comment: At a guess the error happens when you `print(i)` as you have gone through the whole list and then added `1` to `i` on the last iteration which makes it `1` larger than the length of the list

Comment: Normally, if the code is run from the command line the exception will be silently consumed, but here you are running under an IDE, which tries to help you by showing you where the exception occurs.

Comment: Can you please run this code in a shell that provides the full traceback? Keep in mind that we cannot run the code ourselves since the input is missing. Are you sure this is actually a fat exception and not, say, an informational popup in a debug run? See the [mre] help page how to best help us help you with debugging issues.

Comment: `except:` are evil - specify the error you want to catch - in this case probably `except ValueError:` or `except (ValueError, WhatEverError):` if you need to catch multiples

Comment: Not sure it's been mentioned so far, but this code is ironpython and thus probably python 2.7. Additionally, I don't think it can be run in an IDE as the interpreter is embedded within Mechanical

Answer (score -1):

I don't see anything wrong in the code, but why don't you try a simpler approach. It would be also be useful for you to figure out other errors besides ValueError.

```
if B.Name in part_name:
    indx = part_name.index(B.Name)
    B.Thickness = Quantity(thickness[indx])
else:
    i+=1
```